# Meaning of volume names in ASOIAF books?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Does anyone know true meaning of volume names in *A Song of Ice and Fire* books? (e.g., *Steel and Snow*, *Dreams and Dust*).

In some regions (including [UK, Australia, and Israel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Storm_of_Swords)), these were appended when certain novels were published as two volumes:

- *A Storm of Swords Part 1: **Steel and Snow***.
- *A Storm of Swords Part 2: **Blood and gold***.
- *A Dance with Dragons Part 1: **Dreams and Dust***.
- *A Dance with Dragons Part 2: **After the Feast**.

Comment: Those are not original titles. Perhaps they are names of parts of books, i.e. `A Storm of Swords: Steel and Snow`. As far as I know, they have no meaning.

Comment: @TLP, that's correct, by some publishers in both hardcopy and eBook.

Comment: +1 this has always bugged me, especially "After the feast" (what feast? Surely not the Bolton / Manderley / Frey pie feast, hardly seems like a defining moment?). I'd guess they're vague allusions to plot lines (steel & snow = battles and Jon's escapes up north, blood & gold = the two big weddings, dreams & dust = people pursuing big ambitions over dusty landscapes, after the feast = ???). I know GRRM mentioned he likes abstract, vague, evocative titles (don't remember when), maybe there's some other official comment.

Comment: @user568458 I always assumed "After the feast" referred to "A Feast for Crows", as the first part of ADWD happened during AFFC and the second part/volume takes place _after_ AFFC. But I could be mistaken, I read the books without the splitting into volumes.

Comment: @PrisonMonkeys - Sounds like a good answer to me.

Comment: @prisonmonkeys you are probably right, but it was weird to me in ASOS volume names and I wondered whether George was chosen names? :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find any official statements about this, but they seem like vague descriptions about some of the plot points.

### A Storm of Swords

As @user568458 mentioned in the comments, the Snow in **Steel and Snow** refers to Jon Snow's adventures north of the Wall, while the Steel refers to the battles in the South (I can't directly remember any particular events it points to).

**Blood and Gold** alludes to the two big weddings.

### A Dance with Dragons

**Dreams and Dust** contains people pursuing big ambitions over dusty landscapes (thanks, @user568458).

**After the Feast** is the second part of A Dance with Dragons, where we see events taking place *after* the previous book A Feast for Crows, in contrast to the first part which happens during the events of AFFC.

Comment: pretty good answer :) i was wrong, they have meaning...